# Angular.js $http $window.location and global variables

Tags: http, angularjs, global-variables, window.location

I'm trying to update a global variable within an $http request, redirect to a new page and then print that variable (on error). I'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly, but when I try to print my variable (`$rootscope.adHocLevel2`) it remains empty.
In js file

```
$scope.searchStep2 = function(option) { 
  $http.post($scope.url, { "option" : option}).
    success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.status = status;
      $scope.data = data;
      $rootScope.response = data; 
      })
    .
    error(function(data, status) {
      $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
      $scope.status = status;   
      $rootScope.response = 'Request failed';
      $rootScope.routeAd = {"route": "../adHoc/adhoc.html"};            
      $rootScope.addHocLevel2 = {"suggestedCategory": "Car","suggestedLocLabel": "world","suggestedShadowURL": "http://www.toyota.com/auris/hybrid"};
      $window.location=$rootScope.routeAd.route;            
});
};
```

In Html I'm trying to print

```
<input type="text" ng-model="optLocation" value={{addHocLevel2}} />
```

Thanks ahead

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr example?

Comment: @user2273266 http://plnkr.co/edit/kDSAuqroSJ0Zd94JHtuY?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the above code, you have $window.location = $rootScope.routeAd.route which points to "../adHoc/adhoc.html". This will reload the app and therefore you lose addHocLevel2 value.

You will need to redirect to its hash route path (e.g. #/adhoc) - as per your routeProvider.when("/adhoc") config, rather than ../adHoc/adhoc.html.

Also I think the best way when moving within the angular's one page app is to use $location.path(yourRoutePath) rather than $window.location unless you want to change location entirely (new URL somewhere).

e.g

You have 2 routes setup:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', { templateUrl:'/main/main.html',controller:'MainCtrl'})
        .when('/adhoc', { templateUrl: '/adHoc/adhoc.html',controller:'AdHocCtrl});
}
```

Then say you want to redirect from /main to /adhoc, it goes something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',function($rootScope,$scope,$location,$http){
    $http.post(...).error(function(data,status){
       $rootScope.addHocLevel2 = {...};
       $location.path("/adhoc"); // this will 'redirect' you to adHoc/adhoc.html page
    }
})
```

Update: I updated your plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/01lfzd4Q4bFoSPAB4WIF/
This is how I would do it - I'm sure there are another approaches. I use index.html as the template and have main.html and adhoc.html as the 2 other pages that you can switch to based on the URL.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, I changed the route to $rootScope.routeAd = {"route": "../adHoc/#adhoc.html"}; and I'm getting an error, is the syntax correct?

Comment: Could you please provide your routerProvider settings? I updated the above with more explanation. try $location.path("adhoc") or $location.path("adhoc.html") depending on the 'routerProvider.when()' set in the routerProvider.